# Как написать однострочный код?

Tags: python

Можно ли много действий выполнять в одной строке ?

```
def genMAIL(Fname, Tname){
    return [Fname,Tname].replace(' ','').tolower(),'@mail.com'

}
```

Нужно соединить 2 строки, заменить пробелы на ничего, перевести в нижний регистр и добавить @mail.com.
И всё это сделать в одну строку кода

Можете дать ссылку на туториал, как правильно реализовывать код вот так ?

Comment: `(Fname + Tname).replace(' ', '').lower() + '@mail.com'`

Comment: Выполнить то можно главное чтобы это потом никому не приходилось читать и вникать... И Вам в том числе через несколько месяцев...

Answer (score 1):

так устроит?

```
genMAIL = lambda Fname, Tname: (Fname.replace(' ','') + Tname.replace(' ','') + '@mail.com').lower()

print(genMAIL('test test2', 'Big Boom'))
```

вот так чуть покороче:

```
genMAIL = lambda Fname, Tname: ((Fname + Tname).replace(' ','') + '@mail.com').lower()
```

вот так чуть более универсально но чуть подлиннее:

```
genMAIL = lambda Fname, Tname: ''.join([Fname, Tname, '@mail.com']).replace(' ','').lower()
```

Comment: Вопрос — зачем? Плюс именование лямбда-функции — это плохо.

Comment: чем именование плохо?

Comment: Ну, на мой взгляд если функция анонимная — то предполагается, что она будет использована без имени. [Также вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38381556/is-it-pythonic-naming-lambdas).